# Install azure integration runtime on linux and move data from Linux to Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, redhat, rhel

I want to move data from **Linux RHEL 8.5** to **Azure blob storage**.
I have a server of **postgreSQL** running on that linux vm and I want to move some table periodically from vm to azure blob storage.
After reading their official documentation, Azure IR only support windows environment.
Is there any way that I can use **Azure data factory** to move data from **linux RHEL 8.5** to Azure blob storage?

Answer (score 0):

Azure data factory has a connector to PostgreSQL. If your server can be connected from the internet, then you can use data factory directly. If your server is behind a firewall, you need to install self hosted IR, which you will need to install on another (windows) server, in the same network of your PostgreSQL server.

Comment: yes unfortunately, or server is behind a firewall.